# PowerApps Canvas app - Email format validation in text field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-canvas

I have a canvas app with a text field for a user to enter their personal email address.

Is there a way I can throw an error if they didn't enter in the correct format?

Try to force them to use correct email format?

For example, a user enters Cshoemaker24 (rather than Cshoemaker24@gmail.com).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IsMatch` function in Power Apps for email validation on the text input field.

**Example**:

You can use formula like below on your "Submit" button control which submits the form:

```
If(
    IsMatch(DataCardValue1.Text, Match.Email ),
    SubmitForm(SharePointForm1), 
    Notify("Please enter valid email address", NotificationType.Error)
)
```

Where `DataCardValue1` is the name of text input field.

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  I really appreciate it.